# HTML element not in a ready state after View.Render called

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a View code and the render inside the code looked like following.

```
 render: function() {
  var $el = $(this.el);
  $el.html(this.template({diarysCollection: this.collection}));


  $("#updateStatusContent").charCount({
      css:'counter',
      cssWarning:'counter_warning',
      cssExceeded:'counter_exceeded',
      allowed:750,
      warning:50,
      counterText:text_characters_left + " "
  });
 .....
```

But the html element *updateStatusContent* present in the template is not ready so jquery charcount dosen't work.

Comment: If i were you, i would use `this.$el.find('#updateStatusContent')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the element within the scope of the current view:

```
this.$('#updateStatusContent')
```

Documentation:

[view.$(selector)](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)